# Getting error when sending a file stream through a POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-drive-api, axios

I have created a web service to connect with google drive API. Also there is an another system which is frontend developed using react js. I need to send a file from react system to google drive through the web service which I developed. For that I used file stream. When I send it, I got an error which says "part.body.pipe is not a function". This comes from the google drive api.

Below code is sample code for POST request which I sent.

```
const axios = require('axios');
const fs    = require('fs');

const stream = fs.createReadStream('./download.jpg');

axios.post('http://localhost:3008/google-drive/upload-file', {
        stream,
        name: 'add.jpg',
        mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
    }
)
.then((res) => {
    console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)
    console.log(res)
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.error(error)
})
```

Below is the google drive integration for file upload.

```js
function uploadFiles(auth, mainRequest, mainResponse) {
    const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});

    const {
        stream,
        name,
        mimeType,
    } = mainRequest.body;

    let fileMetaData = {
        name,
    };

    let media = {
        mimeType,
        body: stream,
    };

    drive.files.create({
        media,
        resource: fileMetaData,
        fields: 'id',
    }, (error, file) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);

            return mainResponse.status(200).json({
                message: 'The API returned an error: ' + error
            });
        }

        return mainResponse.status(200).json({
            fileId: file.id
        });
    });
}
```

I think the problem is in `createReadStream`. I'm not sure I used it correctly or not.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score -1):

You made a mistake in the fs

Rather try using this synchronous func

```
fs.readFileSync('filename.jpg','utf8')
```

Comment: you are saying, instead of `createReadStream` use `readFileSync`.  Aren't you?

Comment: yeah exactly or you can use async func readFile but i wouldn’t bother with it

Comment: But in the google drive api integration, they request a stream.